# Mysql Database schema for daily deals website: like Groupon

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I want to create one database which can handle daily deals provided by partners.Also i want to design it in such way so that database it self will not allow duplicate data by using combination of lat-long, name & date-time. As for now i have one provider but in future i might get deals from 2-3 different partners.

Is one table is enough for above requirement which will handle all the data.

I will really apreciate any comments/ suggestions or hints to get me start or push in right direction. Any type of reference info.

Please let me know if need some more information or i am not clear about any point...

Regards,
K

Comment: It seems to me that you need to read a good book (or tutorials) on 'database normalization'. Read this for an introduction: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 2):

I would at first put the partners in a separate table, to store all their information. Then, the deals only need a partnerid. It is unclear to me what these deals are, and if you may need a separate table with product information, so a deal is actually a link between a product and a provider, for a given period of time.
In that case, you need three tables at least to store just the deals, apart from any orders and other information you might need.

But if you start modeling, it is strongly advised that you do some reading about database normalization. It will give you a guide to what you should store in which table.

http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm